# そらのおとしもの - "Heaven's Lost Property" or "What fell from the sky?"

Tags: translation, names, anime

I am watching an anime called そらのおとしもの (Sora no Otoshimono). There are two translations: the one is "Heaven's Lost Property" and the other is "What fell from from the sky?"

I'm pretty sure that the first translation in correct, since there is no question mark on the original Japanese title. If the second was correct, it would have か (the question particle) and a question mark.

But I'm not really sure about the correct translation. Can you help me? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Bajiru

Comment: Both translation seem reasonable. The translation 'what fell from the sky' isn't a question. It's the 'what' meaning 'the thing that' e.g. 'what fell from the sky was an stunned bird'.

Comment: Where did you see "What fell from the sky"? I've only ever seen it called "Heaven's Lost Property" in English.

Comment: @Ataraxia Unfortunately, I do not remember where I have seen it.. But I do remember that I have seen it somewhere.

Comment: @Bajiru Okay, just curious. Great anime, either way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Heaven's lost property" is the only correct (literal) translation of 空{そら}の落{おと}し物{もの}, mainly because 落し物 is a fixed word meaning "lost property", and 落とす is a transitive verb so it has to mean "dropped/lost item (i.e. by someone or something else)" as opposed to a "fallen item" which would use the verb 落{お}ちる.

Answer (score 1):

It would be ""Heaven's Lost Property" because おとしもの means "lost property".

"What fell from the sky?" would be translated as 何が空から落ちたの?. And "What(The thing that) fell from the sky" would be translated as 空から落ちたもの.

There's also the possibility that the author purposely used おとしもの as 落ちたもの.